# How to check a specific value in a for loop and then end it?

Tags: python, csv

Today is my first time learning csv and python. Sorry if i am asking a question that has been answered. I am using csv dictreader. lets say i have a file with these rows:

```
{'age': '20', 'name': 'Alice'}
{'age': '21', 'name': 'Freddie'}
{'age': '17', 'name': 'Bob'}
```

I will be creating a program that allow user to input their name. Should it match the data, it will output true. I tried using for loop and an if else statement inside.

However, it loops the entire data instead of the specific data i am looking at. For example, if i input "Bob", i get

```
Enter Name:Bob
No record found
No record found
true
```

instead of

```
Enter Name:Bob
true
```

I believe this is because of the for loop I've created but I'm still not sure how to counter it.

```
import  csv

name1 = input("Enter Name:")

filePath = "data.csv"
with open(filePath) as  csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    for row in reader:
        if name1 == row['name']:
            print("true")       
            break            
        else:                     
            print("No record found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bob` is in the last row, so it has to iterate over all the rows from the start till it finds `Bob` and then it exists.

You probably want to just print `No records found` at the end, not in every iteration. Here is a suggestion using a flag to remember if the term was found or not:

```
import  csv

name1 = input("Enter Name:")
was_found = False

filePath = "data.csv"
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    for row in reader:
        if name1 == row['name']:
            print("true")
            was_found = True
            break            

if not was_found:
    # looked at every row and did not find search term
    print("No record found")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to put the `No record found` message into the `for` loop.

Whatever you put into the `for` loop can be run 0, 1 or many times. For the `No record found` message, the *many* doesn't make sense.

Therefore that message has to go outside the `for` loop:

```
for row in reader:
    if row['name'] == name1:
        print("found it")
        return
print("no record found")
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` (and `while`) loops in Python actually can have an `else` after them. This clause will only be entered if the loop was not interrupted by a `break`. So you can just de-indent your `else` clause:

```
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    for row in reader:
        if name1 == row['name']:
            print("true")       
            break
    else:                     
        print("No record found")
```